# Нужно ли поставить запятую в следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

> Она ушла(,) не сказав ни слова.

Думаю, что здесь деепричастие утратило свое глагольное значение, поэтому запятую не надо ставить.

Comment: Деепричастный оборот нужно обособить.

Answer (score 3):

*Она ушла, **не сказав ни слова.***

Это **деепричастный оборот**, значение времени он не утратил. Оборот обозначает действие, дополнительное по отношению к основному действию: ушла и при этом не сказала ни слова.

Можно записать: *Она ушла молча, не сказав ни слова.* Мы видим, что по семантике оборот имеет значение наречия/обстоятельства, но его **структура** не позволяет приравнять его к необособленному обстоятельству. Оборот достаточно **распространен**, деепричастие **совершенного вида**. Чаще не обособляются одиночные деепричастия несовершенного вида.

В примерах **[из Нацкорпуса](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CoEBIi4KLAoqCiRwcmlfY2F0OtGF0YPQtNC%2B0LbQtdGB0YLQstC10L3QvdCw0Y8aAggBKhgKCAgAEAoYMiAKEAUgAEAFagQwLjk1eAAyAggBOgEBQi4KLAoqCgNyZXESIwoh0L3QtSDRgdC60LDQt9Cw0LIg0L3QuCDRgdC70L7QstCwMAA=)** оборот обособляется:

*На каждой было одно и то же: кто-то долго дышал, а потом клал трубку, **не сказав ни слова*** (Андрей Волос, 2001).

Comment: Одиночные деепричастия несовершенного вида, наоборот, не обособляются.

Comment: Извините, случайно пропустила НЕ.

Comment: Мне кажется, Sharon, вот эти предложения нагляднее, ближе к тому, что в вопросе. *Но они походили по дому, взяли старый бабкин платок и **ушли,** не сказав ни слова* (Анатолий Кузнецов. Бабий яр). *Я **ушел,** не сказав ни слова* (Владимир Приданников. Путь самоотверженного ). *...в 7 час. собралась и куда-то **ушла,** не сказав ни слова* (В. С. Савельев. Дневник).

Comment: Тут вот что интересно: оборот «не сказав ни слова» скорее всего вообще всегда обособляется, а не только по отношению к глаголу «ушел». Я также думаю, что оборот «не ответив» всегда обособляется тоже. Что-то мешает этим формам проявить  наречное значение.